# How do I correct for magnetic declination?

Tags: hiking, compasses

I have a question about magnetic declination as it pertains to its use with compass navigation.

I currently live in Albuquerque New Mexico which currently has a magnetic declination of 8°E.

Let's say that I am trying to get to a location that is due True North (0°) from where I am currently located.
I align myself and compass so that I am pointing towards the Magnetic North (Put Fred in the Shed all that stuff). How would I get to my actual location?
Would I walk 8 degrees east or west of Magnetic North?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  Are you looking for [an easy way to remember if you add magnetic declination to magnetic bearings or true bearings](/q/22337/11623)?

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. "straight ahead" is not a cardinal direction. 0 degrees would be called "due north" or "towards (true) north".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way to remember if you add magnetic declination to magnetic bearings or true bearings?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/22337/is-there-an-easy-way-to-remember-if-you-add-magnetic-declination-to-magnetic-bea)

Comment: Straight ahead true, or straight ahead magnetic?

Comment: The location I am hoping to get to is 0 degrees true north ahead. My compass tells me that I am currently pointing north, but it has a declination of 7.99E. How would I get to my location, would I walk 8 degrees West or East. Sorry for the confusing terminology!

Comment: Welcome to TGO. Generally, you should provide clarification in the question, via the [Edit], not in the comments. Specifically, i'd replace your 7.99° with 8° as most magnetic bearings are only accurate to about  1°. Lastly, are you sure the other Q & A doesn't help?

Comment: Yes; I am looking for a far simpler solution than taking bearings/using a map. Just using a compass

Comment: (If you are replying to a comment, you should add @commenter's_name so we know to whom you are replying. Our comments are otherwise directed at you by default.) Your comment "simpler solution than taking bearings/using a map. Just using a compass" doesn't make much sense. If you know your target is 0°T then you must be using a map. If you are using a compass then you are taking bearings!

Comment: Just saw this post.  Since you @gregkuhn have not accepted an answer I assume you are still waiting for a better one?  NOAA.GOV publishes magnetic declination data every 5 years.  With this data, a computer (i.e. your phone) can take a magnetic reading and adjust it for declination based on the phone's GPS coordinates. Let me know if this interests you and I can drop a more detailed description into an answer for you to check off.

Answer (score 2):

[Declination | NWCG](https://www.nwcg.gov/course/ffm/location/65-declination) provides a good explanation and description.

They start with a map (in this case of the USA, with possibly out of date values) that shows lines connecting locations with equal declination:

[image]

For instance, if you were in California (left coast) the declination is about 10°E.
That means that the compass is pointing too far to the right (East).

Or, if you were in Delaware (right coast) the declination is about 10°W.
That means that the compass is pointing too far to the left (West).

[image]

> I currently live in Albuquerque New Mexico which currently has a magnetic declination of 8.00°E.

Your compass is pointing 8° east of where it should be pointing.
So to go due north, you should be walking 8° to the left of the needle.

It's not likely to be a factor when walking, but if you were flying long distance, you'd also need to be aware that the declination will change as you move farther north through Colorado, Wyoming, and Montana.
By the time you cross the Canadian border, the declination will have increased to about 15°E.
And if you reach northern Canada, the declination changes rapidly enough that in some places magnetic compasses are useless.